# Collector and Field Maps failing to load secure layers - but just for one person

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-collector, arcgis-field-maps

I work as a GIS analyst, and we used Collector/Field Maps daily for field editing and updates. Yesterday, one of my employees started getting red triangles when trying to open our utility map. I have tried everything I can think of and searched for answers, but I'm out of ideas. We completely deleted and re-added him as a member to both server and our arcgis online organization. I have attached an image with a screenshot of the map layers. also, I have copied the error message that goes along with the red error triangles at the end of this message. We run arcgis server, and all our feature services are published straight from a versioned SDE layer to the stand-alone server with ADS security. I'm not a developer, so if someone has some ideas, I'll need walkthroughs on what to do if it involves scripting, coding, etc.

Domain: com.esri.arcgis.runtime.services.error
Code: 403
Description: User does not have permissions to access 'iub_utilities/iub_chw.mapserver'.
[image]